# Aloe leaves turned gelatinous

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, aloe

I have a small aloe plant that someone gave me a while back and it's been doing well. They took some of their cuttings and planted them in a small pot. The longest leaf is probably the length of my hand. I set it outside for some sun today and a freak rainstorm occurred. When I got home, most of the leaves had turned into complete jelly with 2 of them turning into jelly at their bases. I had no clue that heavy water could do this.

Is there any way to save/salvage part of the plant and replant them like my friend initially did? Or should I just give up?

Comment: When rooting cuttings from most succulents the cut surface should dry and scab over before putting in soil. This gives some protection from soil bacteria, etc.You didn't mention if you dried the cuttings before planting.

Comment: @TimNevins No I didn't. Would it be okay if just sticking it in if it's fresh new potting soil? Or should I take them back out and let them it dry?

Comment: Were your plants acclimated before taking them out of doors in the sun?

Comment: @stormy not really... I just thought it needed sunlight and my windows are always shadowed (at the backside of an apartment building away from the morning sun with tall woods). And they're floor length windows, so we cant really set them in front because of our cat. I try to bring it outside in the mornings sometimes so it can get sun. Should I not be? I tried to leave it out one day and the next morning there was tons of super tiny bugs surrounding it so I noped that.

Comment: @stormy It's not strong though, the small deck doesn't get much direct sunlight when I do bring it out. It was acclimated before it came into my possession.

Comment: Plants that are not used to direct sunlight, out of doors in the direct sun will get 'sunburned'.  While plants are indoors without that intensity and spectrum the epidermis of the leaves/stems THINS.  A plant indoors does not need to put energy into building defenses against the IR of the sun.  When you take a plant with a thin epidermis out into direct sunlight...well, it could be death, gelatinous or not.  Potted plants planted in potting soil which is absolutely critical, when taken out of doors most certainly can get a bit of inoculation by insects/disease.  Not a big deal if healthy.

Comment: Never take a plant that is used to the indoors out in the sun. Low light indoors makes thin epidermis layers on the leaves. It also makes larger thinner leaves. It also cuts down photosynthesis which is necessary for growth, reproduction. A weakened plant that maybe was stressed by the outdoors environment; temperature changes, humidity change, sun burn because the epidermis wasn't thick enough to screen harmful sun IR, will cause that plant to become a restaurant for insects, susceptible to disease. Healthy plants can compete. When unhealthy, plants are easily targeted by disease and insects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aloe plants do not need a lot of water. Their leaves are designed to hold on to water during drought, like a cactus which is related.

The leaves are turgid and because of that, it has stopped photosynthesising because the stomata have closed.
Personally, I would keep it dry and unwatered for a while. Place south facing BUT NOT in direct sunlight.

This is a very tough plant and it should return. Just give it time to recover.